# Does Envoy support TCP proxy?

Tags: envoyproxy

Hello can you please let me know if Envoy ( https://lyft.github.io/envoy/ ) support TCP proxy? I saw that external clients can connect to the “Front” Envoy Edge Proxy using HTTP,TLS. Can you please let me know if there is any possibility for external clients to connect using TCP connection? Some kind of HAProxy replacement. For example:

request tcp ip:port   0.0.0.0:7000

forwarded tcp ip:port
192.168.1.11:8000

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Envoy supports [TCP proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/tcp_proxy):

> Since Envoy is fundamentally written as a L3/L4 server, basic L3/L4 proxy is easily implemented.

It seems there is no example for TCP proxying at the moment but you could try the [suggested reference](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/filter/network/tcp_proxy/v2/tcp_proxy.proto.html) for enabling Envoy to do what you wish.

> there is any possibility for external clients to connect using TCP connection?

I guess it depends more on your network setup than on Envoy setup.

Comment: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/listeners/tcp_proxy